# How to get selected tabs id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get selected tabs **id** only if I click on the tabs not click inside the tabs. How do it using jquery version 1.9.1? fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/tbEq6/240/

Js:

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); 
$("#tabs").click(function(e){ 
      alert($("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id"));
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the element your click handler is attached to to the header of your tab `.ui-tabs-anchor` :

```
$(".ui-tabs-anchor").click(function(e){ 
      alert($("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much..Working:)

Comment: Don't forget to validate this answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Ya..your answer is useful..Thank you.